# Samba logging all to get logs about all user activities on shared folders and files

Tags: ubuntu, logging, samba

How can I get logs for all user activities on files and folders in samba sharing.
Please let me know what changes to be done on samba configuration file `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

My `/etc/samba/smb.conf` contains

```
log level = 3
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%p

max log size = 5000
debug timestamp = yes
```

As of now my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` having configuration as above. But this is not giving a proper log file.

Comment: In what way is this not providing what you want ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are looking for these settings;

http://moiristo.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/samba-logging-user-activity/
http://oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch04_08.html

You can see writes, opens, deletes etc but be warned : Samba logs **A LOT!!!** of information when you enable these options, if its a really busy server, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the instructions in the blog link of the other answer were slightly out of date for Samba 4.15 (on my Ubuntu 22.04 server). What I did:

In `smb.conf`

```
[share]
    vfs objects = full_audit
    full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S
    full_audit:success = mkdirat renameat unlinkat pwrite
    full_audit:failure = none
    full_audit:facility = LOCAL7
    full_audit:priority = NOTICE
```

In `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`, I appended

```
local7.*                        /var/log/samba/log.audit
```

and then I had to give permission to rsyslog (which runs with the user `syslog`) to write to `/var/log/samba/log.audit`

```
sudo usermod -aG adm syslog # /var/log/samba folder's group is adm
sudo chown g+rw /var/log/samba
```